# Cannot Access Javascript API for Office from within a <script> in a Dialog

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-ui-fabric

What follows is the HTML file that is passed to **displayDialogAsync**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
4  See LICENSE in the project root for license information -->
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- For the Office UI Fabric, go to http://aka.ms/office-ui-fabric to learn more. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/fabric.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/fabric.components.min.css">
  <script>
    Office.initialize = function(reason) {


      write();


    }

    function write() {

      // If I uncomment the line below, the text in the dialog box will NOT be updated            
      //var email = Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress;

      $("#firstName").text("John");
      $("#lastName").text("Doe");
      $("#gender").text("Male");
      $("#knownas").text("John Doe");
      $("#citizenship").text("Antarctica");
      $("#language").text("Esperanto");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="ms-Gridc ms-font-xxl ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semilight">
    <div class="ms-Grid-row">
      <div class="ms-Grid-col"><span id="firstName"></span></div>
      <div class="ms-Grid-col"><span id="lastName"></span></div>
      <div class="ms-Grid-col"><span id="gender"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-Grid-row">
      <div class="ms-Grid-col"><span id="knownas"></span></div>
      <div class="ms-Grid-col"><span id="citizenship"></span></div>
      <div class="ms-Grid-col"><span id="language"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Whenever I try to use anything from the Office JavaScript API I notice that my Dialog Box shows up blank.

In the sample, all I'm doing is assigning a value to a variable and the rest of the code stops working.  No error messages appear on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. I found the following in the [documentation for the dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins):

> The `messageParent` function is one of only two Office APIs that can be called in the dialog box. The other is `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported`.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It was a frustrating problem.

I'll go through that documentation again; only with new eyes this time :)

Comment: **workaround**:  i used localStorage.SetItem to put the Office object in local storage then retrieved the data to display in the dialogbox with localStorage.GetItem